# Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)):

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting below error, simply referencing code from link : **https://github.com/Nasruddin/spring-boot-jwt-auth**. In this example, I used Spring Boot Parent version `<version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>`. No customization yet and I am getting below.

Could anyone please guide on this ?

Any help on this? Please let me know if need any other details.

Updates: I am using below curl

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"user","password":"user"}' http://localhost:9000/api/auth/register
```

Error below for reference..

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3750d34d; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:223) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:201) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at com.javatab.security.AuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationTokenFilter.java:46) [classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.javatab.security.AuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationTokenFilter.java:46) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

Comment: exactly what code are you trying to parse?

Comment: Your JSON file or request is malformed, can you double check/attach that?

Comment: Updated details. Using Windows OS

Comment: Post the actual JSON you use. Nobody can do the curl command to your localhost, even if they wanted to.